# Blender Doughnut Sprinkles: Replacing points with Cylinder object does not preserve scale of Object

Tags: geometry-nodes

New to blender and doing the doughnut tutorial. For some reason, When I link the  Cylinder Object Info node into the Instance on Points Node, the cylinders that appear on the points are microscopic instead of the same size as the Object. Only after increasing the scale from 1 to 20 does the Cylinder instance actually look like the object. The scale of the cylinder has been applied.

I am using Blender version 3.6.5
See screenshots for differences in scale.

Why does this happen? Why are the cylinder instances not the same size as the object when the scale is 1?

[image: Instance on Points scale Set to 20 for X, Y, Z coordinates]

[image: Instance on Points scale Set to 1 for X, Y, Z coordinates]

Comment: Your icing's scale seems to be 0.038, maybe pressing CTRL+A and applying the scale will help?